# Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'?

Tags: swift

**I know there is another thread with the same question, but it doesn't tell what is actually causing the problem**

Im new to swift, so Im a bit confused on this.
I wrote a very simple program that is supposed to start with a default number of followers (0) and assign that to 'defaultfollowers' and once that becomes 1 its supposed become "followers", but I get the error "Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'". What is causing this and **why**

```
    var followerdeafault = 0
var followers = 0
if (followerdeafault++){
 var followers = followerdeafault

}
```

Comment: `followerdeafault++` returns an Int. `if` takes a Bool. These don't match.

Comment: You aren't comparing the value properly. Read up on [Comparison Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID70).

Comment: This is exactly why `++` is being deprecated. Horrible sideeffects in `if` conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift you can't implicitly substitute Int instead of Bool. This was done to prevent confusion and make code more readable.

So instead of this

```
let x = 10
if x { /* do something */ }
```

You have to write this:

```
let x = 10
if x != 0 { /* do something */ }
```

Also you can't pass an Optional instead of Bool to check if it's `nil`, as you would do in Objective-C. Use explicit comparison instead:

```
if myObject != nil { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments said, you're trying to use an `Int` in a `Bool` comparison statement. What you're looking for is probably something like this:

```
if followerdeafuaut++ == 1 { ... }
```

Also side note: the `++` operator is deprecated, moving towards using `+=`